# Do some phones automatically download voicemail?

Tags: voicemail

On my Focus S, when I press the voicemail button it dials the voicemail service.

Do some phones skip this step, by automatically downloading the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you phone and carrier supports it, you will have Visual Voicemail enabled. I assume this is what you are talking about.

When it is enabled, you can swipe left from the Phone application to see a list of voicemails in your account. You can play or delete a single one from that screen. I don't think your phone automatically download them, but instead streams it over once you tell it to play a specific one. You can't really tell the difference though.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the pointer. AT&T's website says Visual Voicemail is included with Windows Phones on the 4G LTE plan. My phone has the 4G status icon. The instructions don't match up with the website: "look under Device instructions > Calling features > Voicemail to find out how to set up the Visual Voicemail feature on your device." [There is no](http://www.att.com/devicehowto/?_requestid=277832) `Calling features` item.

Comment: A while ago AT&T changed there network to make 3G say 4G. Which phone do you have? If you phone supports LTE then you should have it.

Comment: Actually I found the Voicemail item, but doesn't talk about Visual Voicemail. I have a Samsung Focus S.

Comment: I don't have a reference but I think the Focus S won't get Visual Voicemail enabled until the Tango update ships. Since that is happening now, I would suspect once your phone updates you should see it.

Comment: The left-swipe gesture isn't active for me.

Comment: Okay, Tango is the 7.8 update?

Comment: No. Mango > Tango > 7.8. Technically, Mango enabled the phones to do Visual Voicemail, but ATT has said they won't/can't enable it on all devices. From this I have read ATT will enable it on the Focus S when they ship on the Tango update. I would imagine you should get it soon.

Comment: Well I definitely have Mango. OS version: 7.10.8773.98. Oh wait, I took that for a greater than symbol. I see what you're saying now.